# AttributeError: module 'pandas.io' has no attribute 'common'

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime (2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime (2018,1,1)

df=web.DataReader('TSLA', 'morningstar', start, end)
print(df.head())
```

Trying to use the above code, but I get the error:

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/compat/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  import pandas.io.common as com

AttributeError: module 'pandas.io' has no attribute 'common'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your python environment not the code.

When I run your code on my environment `Python 3.6.4`, your code produces the following output.

```
                   Close  High   Low  Open    Volume
Symbol Date                                         
TSLA   2010-06-29   23.9  25.0  17.5  19.0  18783276
       2010-06-30   23.8  30.4  23.3  26.0  17194394
       2010-07-01   22.0  25.9  20.3  25.0   8216789
       2010-07-02   19.2  23.1  18.7  23.0   5135795
       2010-07-05   19.2  19.2  19.2  19.2         0
```

You will need to upgrade your environment, Please issue the following commands at terminal & then restart your python environment.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Comment: I am using spyder with anaconda. Could this be the problem?
I have tried conda update --all but it doesn't seem to resolve. I get a different error everytime.
Since I use anaconda, I can't use pip?

Comment: You can use pip with anaconda. Also, you can just run the file from your terminal directly using `python <filename.py>` and see if you face any issues. if that didn't work then send me your python version.

Comment: I had an error of `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline` Probably an issue with me using a mac. Nevertheless, the code seems to be working in spyder now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm using a mac as well, I don't have the error you mentioned above.